# How to create a component from a variable loaded from server that contains react component code?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create component on the fly from my database where I will be storing components code. Here is what I am trying

```
const Home: NextPage = (data : any) => {
    
        const Test = data.compData // contains the component code
    
        return (
        <>
            
            <h1 id='nice' > this is a nice h1 tag</h1>
            <Test />
        </>
        )
    }
```

If I console.log the data I am getting, here is the loaded data from server

```
export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Testing component loading....</h1>
   </div>
  )
}
```

Error I am getting

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid tag: export default function test() {
 return (
    <div>
      <h1>testing component loading....</h1>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: The "HTML" in the javascript isn't a string -- it's JSX which is syntactic sugar on top of React.createElement.

You can have strings of html if you use https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: yes want to use jsx so that can add logical code, conditions, loops etc in the code instead of a normal html code

Comment: The browser doesn't understand JSX -- there's steps in babel that transform the JSX into calls of React.CreateElement https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements

You could use then use eval, but that'd be pretty bad practice imo.

Comment: there is no other ways to achieve components making from variables? :(

Comment: You can, I'm just pointing out the the vision you have doesn't make sense.

Here's a component from a prop variable: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sanne-bl5frw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: wow, your one is perfectly working, but for me it just shows the html as is! I am loading the component from an api result in getInitialProps. Why I am seeing the plain html ?

Comment: Ok, so when the html is in the main react project, its get a chance get compiled, if its loaded from a server in run time, it doesn't get a chance get compiled, thats why it shows as plain html..